# Write a program that subsets the loads and subsets the stock market data in target.csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Write a program that subsets the loads and subsets the stock market data in target.csv.

Load the the data from target.csv as target.
Create a new data frame, tgt_march, by subsetting the last 19 days of the target data frame.
Create a new data frame, tgt_vol, by subsetting the Date and Volume columns.
Create a new data frame, tgt_close, by subsetting the Date and Close columns.
Using the template from this link, create separate line charts for Volume and Close and upload the resulting output.
If the input is:

3

The output is:

The volume of TGT on 2018-03-05 is 7654766.
The closing stock price of TGT on 2018-03-05 is $75.14.

**My code:
**
import pandas as pd

tgt = pd.read_csv('target.csv')
df=tgt

tgt_march = df[-19:]

tgt_vol = df[['Date', 'Volume']]
tgt_close = df[ ['Date', 'Close']]

day = int(input()) - 1

volume_row = tgt_vol.iloc[[day]]
volume = volume_row.iloc[0][1]

close_row = tgt_close.iloc[[day]]
close = close_row.iloc[0][1]

date = tgt_march.iloc[[day]].iloc[0][0]

print("The volume of TGT on " + str(date) + " is " + str(int(volume)) + ".")
print("The closing stock price of TGT on " + str(date) + " is $" + str(close) + ".")

**My output with 3 as the input:
**
The volume of TGT on 2018-03-05 is 94400.
The closing stock price of TGT on 2018-03-05 is $69.75.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
# import the pandas module
import pandas as pd

tgt = pd.read_csv('target.csv') # load the target.csv file

tgt_march = tgt[-19:] # subset the last 19 days of the dataframe

tgt_vol = tgt[['Date', 'Volume']]  # subset tgt_march and create a data frame that contains the columns: Date and Volume

tgt_close =tgt[ ['Date', 'Close']][ ['Date', 'Close']] # subset tgt_march and create a data frame that contains the columns: Date and Closing

day = int(input())-20


volume_row = tgt_vol.iloc[[day]] 
volume = volume_row.iloc[0][1] # subset the specific row of tgt_vol for the given day
volume = volume_row.iloc[0][1] # gets the volume for the given day

close_row = tgt_close.iloc[[day]]# subset the specific row of tgt_close for the given day
close = close_row.iloc[0][1] # gets the closing stock price for the given day

date = tgt_march.iloc[[day]].iloc[0][0] # gets the date

print("The volume of TGT on " + str(date) + " is " + str(int(volume)) + ".")
print("The closing stock price of TGT on " + str(date) + " is $" + str(close) + ".")
```